# SwiftUI Zstack – Make element ignore safe area and another one don't

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, zstack

I have a Zstack like this:

```
ZStack {
  Image("beach")
    .resizable()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .scaledToFill()

  VStack {
    // with a lot of stuff
  }
}
```

I want the image to ignore the safe area, but the `Vstack` must respect the safe area.

The image is a background image that should cover all the area.

This code I have is making the `VStack` full screen too and I don't want that.

Why everything is not respecting the safe area is a mystery, because the respective modifier is applied to the image only.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put your image in the `.background`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            // lots of stuff
            Color.red
            Color.blue
        }
        .background(
            Image("beach")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .scaledToFill()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Image is not displayed on my side

Answer (score 14):

The reason why it doesn't work with your example is that you are using `scaledToFill()` modifier on image, and here it matters in this particular case.

First you declared `ZStack` which is itself doesn't ignore safe area. After you put `Image` and `resizable`. What resizable does, is it stretches the image to fit its view, in your case it is the `ZStack`.

Let's see what we have until now.We have an image which stretches till the safe area.

```
ZStack {
  Image("Breakfast").resizable()       

}
```

[image]

So from now on you put `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` on `Image`, which lets the image cover all the area(ignore safe area).
Now you have `Zstack` which respects safe area, and `Image` which ignores safe area. This let you put `VStack` in `ZStack` and add staff inside it. `VStack` will fill its parent view, which is `ZStack`, so it too will respect safe area(See code and image below).

```
ZStack {
  Image("Breakfast").resizable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)       

  VStack {
    Text("hello")
    Spacer()
  }
}
```

[image]

And here at last you add `.scaledToFill()` modifier, which stretches the image to contain all the area, and by doing this it makes `ZStack` view to become the hole area, as fitting view's (ZStack, HStack, VStack) calculates its size based on its content.

[image]

Useful link:

[Fitting and filling views in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/05/20/fitting-and-filling-view-in-swiftui/)

[How to resize a SwiftUI Image and keep its aspect ratio](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-resize-swiftui-image-and-keep-aspect-ratio/)

Answer (score 7):

Another way that worked for me is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
                .background(
                    Image("beach")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .scaledToFill()
                )
            
            VStack {
                // lots of stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In my case, when trying the other solution of putting .background on VStack the image did not fill the entire screen, instead it shrank to fit the size of what was in the VStack.

Comment: I go with that one! Great solution!